# TypeScript generic for sum of string or number array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to create a TypeScript function that will take an array of strings or numbers and return either a concatenated string, or the sum of the numbers.

My attempt looks like this:

```
function arrayCat<T extends number | string>(n: Array<T>): string {
  if (n.length > 0) {
    if (typeof n[0] === 'string') {
      return n.join(', ');
    } else if (typeof n[0] === 'number') {
      const v: Array<any> = n;
      const sum: number = v.reduce((prev: number, curr: number)=> {
         return prev + curr;
      });
      return sum.toString();
    }
  }

  return '';
}

console.log(arrayCat([1, 2])); // Outputs: 3
console.log(arrayCat(['fish', 'cow'])); // Outputs: fish, cow
```

But it seems like reverting to `const v: Array<any> = n;` is defeating the purpose of TypeScript.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does not work with this code? (Except for the fact that it accepts `arrayCat([1, 2, 'fish', 'cow'])` and produces a return value that is not mentioned in your expected outcomes.)

Comment: @axiac, The code works as designed, It just seems like it shouldn't be converting the array to `Array<any>`. It feels like it is not using TypeScript correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T extends number | string` does not stick `T` to either `number` or `string`. This means that `Array<T>` may contain both numbers and strings.

The current code [happily accepts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwMLKgHgBVEBTADyhLABMBnRMEAWwCMTUBtAXUQB9FaUVDDABzbgD4AFGABciQgEp5g4WMQBvAFCJEMYIhkA6ADZVRUABaIJiAAyLNO3XoNSomAA4k4BsBzseAF4QxAByVRFRMMdtFxdUEigQVCQwIwArOBEpMIAacMUAbmddAF9SE1oSV0MPb18GAODQsMZWdhineN0IBEFEADd5AEF0LHxkMExbIIYSnsQ+sAHaZnl2tlREOcGjROoQCBIpKU9E4YZmLYKIFNQN6-ZFINs4xd1E5NTEc5JBxAAaiW9wWPTKxVKCSSKSQayYRigcAAykIolJIfEys5sc4vrDwmESrjlrQ4GZTHBRFI0BgcHgpBwAIwFABMXEUxUQAHpuYgAPIgKCeIW0eQAZi0pPJJEp1NpWFwUEZYWAMFolny4T6AHcwhyubyBUKRVAxYg1RrbnAdVL+jK5TTxvTlcy2QVVerNR7dfrOSUtEA) `[1, 2, 'fish', 'cow']` as input and produces an unexpected outcome.

This can be easily repaired by changing the function signature to:

```js
function arrayCat<T extends number[] | string[]>(n: T): string
```

The generic is not even needed in this situation. It can be written as well as:

```js
function arrayCat(n: number[] | string[]): string
```

The rest of the code looks good but on runtime there is not guarantee that all items of the input array are of the same type as the first item.

---

I refactored the code to handle one situation at a time and to validate all items of the input array:

```js
function arrayCat(n: number[] | string[]): string {
    if (n.length === 0) {
        return '';
    }

    if (isStringArray(n)) {
        return n.join(', ');
    }

    if (isNumberArray(n)) {
        return n.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr).toString();
    }

    // Here `n` contains values of more than one type or even of other types (not strings or numbers)
    throw new Error(`Unexpected input: ${n}`);
}

//
// Type guards
function isStringArray(n: (string | number)[]): n is string[] {
    return n.every((i) => typeof i === 'string');
}

function isNumberArray(n: (string | number)[]): n is number[] {
    return n.every((i) => typeof i === 'number');
}
```

Check it [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-fsw6Ho4nUCnM8Qh7YGj6pIknHeieki+X1Fr9awgizTNhk25YLuXa9hkB5HieZ4XuEV5bDsRKktcyBIMy7SouKYAZBcGJgLciCoiIdyYZgmgBGW0x4BAWj4LQqAkOAADWxEkmANSmL+1b-qu9bMT8oGIMxwpAA).

Comment: Only the number typeguard is really necessary. You also don't need the conditional for a zero length array if you make a string array the base case

Comment: If `n` contains values that originate from outside the source code (from user input, from a database, from an HTTP response etc) there is no guarantee that the array contains only strings or only numbers. It may contain mixed types or objects or arrays or booleans. TypeScript is of no help at runtime. The condition for a zero length array is an optimization. It runs much faster than calling `isStringArray()` and `n.join()`. It is also documentation. The reader sees at a glance what is returned when the input array is empty.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you do not need a generic. Simply typing the parameter is enough for this.
`function arrayCat<T extends number | string>(n: T[]): string` becomes
`function arrayCat(n: Array<number | string>): string`.

You can use a type guard to check if it is an array of strings, which will narrow the type of `n` to `number[]` and allow the `reduce()`.

```
// This can be used to check the type of the array and narrow its type.
const isNumberArray = (n: unknown[]): n is number[] => typeof n[0] === 'number';

function arrayCat(n: Array<number | string>): string {
  if (n.length > 0) {
    if (typeof n[0] === 'string') {
      return n.join(', ');
    } else if (isNumberArray(n)) {
      // `n` is `number[]` here.
      const sum: number = n.reduce((prev: number, curr: number)=> {
         return prev + curr;
      });
      return sum.toString();
    }
  }

  return '';
}
```

As @axiac pointed out, this currently allows you to mix array types, which probably isn't what you want. E.g., `arrayCat([1, 2, 'fish', 'cow'])` produces `3fishcow`.  This allowance is more obvious when using direct parameter typing instead of generics.
To fix this, you can make it take an array of either, instead of an array of them mixed: `function arrayCat(n: Array<number | string>): string` becomes `function arrayCat(n: number[] | string[]): string`.

Additional cleanup:
You can use the "early return" pattern to remove a layer of nesting.
Also, while the type guard narrows `n` to `number[]` if it returns `true`, it also *excludes* that possibility in the following if it returns `false`, which in this case leaves `string[]`. By swapping the order of the `if/else if`, it can become a simple `if`.

```
function arrayCat(n: number[] | string[]): string {
  if (n.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }

  if (isNumberArray(n)) {
    // `n` is `number[]` here.

    const sum: number = n.reduce((prev: number, curr: number) => {
      return prev + curr;
    });
    return sum.toString();
  }

  // `n` is `string[]` from here on.
  
  return n.join(', ');
}
```

As the type guard used like this narrows to either `number[]` or `string[]` depending on what it returns, you could also reverse the type guard to check if it is a string array, which makes it a little simpler again:

```
function arrayCat(n: number[] | string[]): string {
  if (n.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }

  if (isStringArray(n)) {
    // `n` is `string[]` here.

    return n.join(', ');
  }

  // `n` is `number[]` from here on.

  const sum: number = n.reduce((prev: number, curr: number) => {
    return prev + curr;
  });
  return sum.toString();
}
```

My personal preference would also be to change the short `if`s to single lines:
`if (n.length === 0) return '';`
`if (isStringArray(n)) return n.join(', ');`

Comment: Hm, I would write it like this: https://tsplay.dev/Nr8p1W, essentially the same thing, but using guard clauses to prevent the unnecessary nesting. Also, the generic `T` is not really doing anything here.

Comment: Yes, I noticed myself that the generic is unused, so I mentioned that. Thanks anyway for pointing it out.

Comment: Put in the answer the refactored version of the code that you have on the TypeScript playground. It is more clear and easier to read (and improve) than the original code.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, it's worth to remember that overload signatures can act as client guards.

The following approach is not exactly what you want, strings are not separated with `,`  but rather directly concatenated but the advantage is that you can't call this on an array that contains both a number and a string.

This makes return values in both cases compatible with the argument type. In your approach, returning the sum of numbers as a string is possibly not what a client code would expect.

```
function arrayCat(n: Array<string>): string;
function arrayCat(n: Array<number>): number;
function arrayCat(n: Array<any>): any {
  return n.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr );
}

console.log(arrayCat([1, 2])); // Outputs: 3
console.log(arrayCat(['fish', 'cow'])); // Outputs: fishcow
console.log(arrayCat([1, 'cow'])); // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the method to the following:

```
function arrayCat<T extends number | string>(n: Array<T>): string {
  if (n.length > 0) {
    if (typeof n[0] === 'string') {
      return n.join(', ');
    } else if (typeof n[0] === 'number') {
      const sum: number = n.reduce((preValue: number | string, currValue: number | string): number => {
        return (preValue as number) + (currValue as number);
      }, 0);
      return sum.toString();
    }
  }

  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're always returning a string you don't need the generic input.

The other quirk is that even though it should be, checking for `typeof n[0] === 'number'` isn't enough to tell the typescript compiler that `n is number[]`.

You can create a quick helper method to make sure that's the case.

You can also just simplify the logic for your string concat as well since in the case of an empty array it's going to return an empty string regardless.

```js
const isNumArray = (arr: string[] | number[]) : arr is number[]  => {
    return typeof arr[0] === "number";
}

function arrayCat(n: string[] | number[]): string {
    if(isNumArray(n)){
        const sum = n.reduce((a,b) => a+b)
        return sum.toString();
    }
    
    return  n.join(", ");
}


console.log(arrayCat([1, 2])); // Outputs: 3
console.log(arrayCat(['fish', 'cow'])); // Outputs: fish, cow
```